# Overriding height of elements

Tags: html, css

I have a page where I'm trying to override the height of the elements on it. I tried defining height, but it won't go below the height of the page as determined by the elements in it.

So how do I set the page at the height I want, regardless of elements?

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="greetings">If
    you would like... </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div class="number2">#1</div>
  <div class="w">
    <center>
      </p>
      <p style="border:5px; 
border-style:solid; border- 
color:#fff; padding: 
0.5em;"><img class="alignnone size- 
medium 
wp-image-41" src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-  
content/uploads/2020
/04/IMG_2020_112949- 
scaled.jpg" alt="" width="95%" height="95%" /></p>
      <p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div class="number2">#2</div>
  <div class="w">
    <center>
      </p>
```

The element defining height here seems to be `w`. How to get css to ignore that and set height at any height I choose, for example `300px`?

At the moment defining height by

```
.page-id-8122 {height: 
300px;}
```

Doesn't work, but defining height at `800000px` does. I'm assuming because there's nothing stopping the page height increasing, but element `w` is stopping it decreasing?

```
<body class="page-template- 
default page page-id-8122 
logged-in admin-bar
no-customize-support wp- 
custom-logo cookies-set 
cookies-accepted has- 
sidebar-right">
<div id="page" 
class="site">
<a class="skip-link screen- 
reader-text" 
href="#content">Skip to
content
</a>
```

Page [here](https://4309.co.uk/greetings-cards)

Html as i wrote it.

```
<div class="number2">#1</div><div class="w"><center><p style="border:5px; border-style:solid; border-color:#fff; padding: 0.5em;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-41" src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/IMG_20203_112949-scaled.jpg" alt="" width="95%" height="95%" /></p></center></div>
```

Comment: Try with overflow: hidden on the body

Comment: You should fix your invalid HTML first. There are closing `</p>` tags with no matching `<p>`. Opening `<p>` tags with no matching `</p>`. Also, the `<center>` tag has been deprecated for years.

Comment: But i like the center tag :-(

Comment: Aside from that, what's causing the problem?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure WordPress just ads random p tags automatically

Comment: I'm pretty sure i didn't write those p tags

Comment: If i delete, WordPress may just add them again.

Comment: @Turnip i can post the html as i wrote it, but that's an expert from my code as found in `view-source`.

Comment: What would you suggest instead of center?

Comment: `p { text-align: center}`

Comment: @disinfor thanks but won't that center p rather than image /element?

Comment: @Juan Elfers thanks. That certainly has worked to some extent...

Comment: @Stackinnerflow an image is an inline element by default, so unless it's display property is set to something other than `inline` or `inline-block`, the image will center. And since, in your case, it's in a `<p>` tag - it will still center.

Comment: @disinfor ok. Thanks.